Gitlab push see 75 Additions and 30 Deletions while creating merge request
After Gitlab push I see 100 Additions and 30 Deletions, and 8 changed files.
While I made only changes to 8 files, not deleted/added any file.
Is it because my local branch is behind master Or some other reason.
If so how I can pull latest changes to my branch without affecting my local changes.
Any help appriciated

the deletions/additions it is talking about is lines in the 8 files.


8 changed files means you have changed 8 files
100 additions (or "insertions") means you have 100 new lines across those 8 files
30 deletions means you have 30 deleted lines across those 8 files

Git only understands "added" and "deleted", it's up to you to infer that deleting one line and adding a new line basically means "this line changed".
It's trivial to test locally:
$ mkdir demo
$ cd demo
$ git init
$ printf '%s\n' line1 line2 line3 line4 > file.txt
$ git add file.txt
$ git commit -m 'initial commit'
$ printf '%s\n' line1 changed2 changed3 line4 > file.txt
$ git add file.txt
$ git commit -m 'changing two lines'
$ git show --stat
commit f4d49adbdf1a3279b892ad6852faf4d59177e4c6 (HEAD -> master)
Author: A U Thor <author@example.com>
Date:   Wed Jul 10 14:06:26 2024 +0200

    changing two lines

 file.txt | 4 ++--
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

